# Generating Query in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am developing a simple PHP report page, containing HTML select tools, where multiple values can be selected.User may select multiple values or he may select All option. If user selects All option, then in query I need not write WHERE condition,but if he selects one or two values from select list, then I need to write only selected values in MySql WHERE. How can I write a generic query to get values from db table.
 This is my first Mysql project, I am unable to write a generic query.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that if the user selects all option you don't need to use a WHERE condition. But I think this is how you need to write a generic query. Always use the where condition. In the very case the user selects all the option, put "and". Suppose you manage to create an array containing all the user selected option, $options. Iterate through each option. Have a start sql statement like "Select * from table where ". Then for each option concatnate "option='$value'". In case the user selects all the option, this is not a problem.

Suppose you manage to put all selected options in an array

```
<?php
$options = array("option1","option2","option3");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
$parts_sql = "";
foreach ($options as $option){
        $parts_sql .="option=$option and ";
}
$sql = $sql . $parts_sql;
$sql = substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-5);
echo $sql;
?>
```

Comment: But using where with all options will take more time to get data from table I guess

Comment: Then, in that case, just have an if statement, have a boolean value which is true is all options has been selected and a different sql then

Comment: That is ok... But I have so many fields and writing an If statement for all fields is not preferable I guess. Is there any other simpler way